# JS/Javascript: .match returns an undefined value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to retrieve every matching word from array but `.match` retuns an undefined function. I'm pretty sure I don't need to convert anything because I'm comparing two strings:

```
var hashtags = [ '#hr', '#acc', '#sales' ];

var message = "hello there #hr #acc";

var filteredMessage = _.filter( message.split( ' ' ), value => value.match( hashtags ) );

 // suppose to return [ '#hr', '#acc' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) incorrectly. This function accepts a regular expression as a parameter and you're using it with an array.

You can achieve what you want by checking if the `value` is one of the array's elements.

Here is an example:

```js
var hashtags = [ '#hr', '#acc', '#sales' ];
var message = "hello there #hr #acc";
var filteredMessage = _.filter( message.split( ' ' ), value => hashtags.indexOf(value) != -1 );
console.log(filteredMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you are trying to do is hashtags are an array and match takes in a regular expression, so I don't think it is the method you want to use.

An alternative solution is to use the intersection function provided by lodash

```
_.intersection(hashtags, message.split(' '))
```

If you do want to use regular expressions (and match) I think you probably have to loop over both arrays to get an intersection.

Comment: All solutions including this one are equivalent, but this one is the most concise. An intersection is exactly what is asked, so this should be the accepted answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using underscore already:

```
filteredMessage = _.filter( message.split( ' ' ), value =>  _.find(hashtags, tag => tag === value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below works for me

`var filteredMessage = message.split(' ').filter(word => hashtags.includes(word));`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variation using Underscore:

```js
_.filter(message.split(' '), _.partial(_.includes, hashtags));
```

However, this is exactly what `_.intersection` does, so in my opinion, [the answer by BBS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871304/1166087) is the most correct.